# Unable to update UILabel from a repeating NSTimer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Why won't the UILabel: "lbl" update on the iPhone?

...
from within a method:

```
myTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(displayDataTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

...

```
-(void) displayDataTimer{

    NSString *temp = [textField1 text];

    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d  %d", j, genValue]];

    //[self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES];    

    j++;
}
```

thx

Comment: Note that [timer fire methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW1) should not be parameterless. They should look like: `-(void)displayDataTimer:(NSTimer *)tim;` Is the timer being created on the main thread? Are you certain that the fire method is being run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your method is firing and you have set an Outlet to that label (named lbl) and that it is wired up and then:

```
self.lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d  %d", j, genValue];
```